# Passport Active Directory node js

Tags: node.js, active-directory, passport.js

Tried this lib, https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory

This config worked:

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var config = { url: 'ldap://dc.domain.com',
               baseDN: 'dc=domain,dc=com',
               username: 'username@domain.com',
               password: 'password' }
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
```

I could authenticate and do lookups in my company's AD.

Instead of this I would like to use passport Active Directory instead so I get sessions etc. https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth

This is the conf for passport ad:

```
var OPTS = {
  server: {
    url: 'ldap://localhost:389',
    bindDn: 'cn=root',
    bindCredentials: 'secret',
    searchBase: 'ou=passport-ldapauth',
    searchFilter: '(uid={{username}})'
  }
};
```

It seems the `bindCredentials` is mandatory. There was no such option in the first one. What am I suppose to enter here if the AD is not password protected? Is baseDN same as bindDN?

Answer (score 0):

`baseDN` in the former seems to be same than `searchBase` in the latter library. `bindDn` and `bindCredentials` in `passport-ldapauth` are needed if your LDAP server requires an authenticated bind. These are equal to `username` and `password` fields in the former library.

If you don't need to bind to perform lookups it should be fine to just not define neither `bindDn` nor `bindCredentials`.